# Firefox keeps opening pdf in preview even when profile has the config to not do so, via python + selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pdf

I'm trying to automatically save a file using python + selenium using firefox as a browser.

The following code doesn't work as expected:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', './temp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml')
profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,application/vnd.fdf,application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml")
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

options = Options()
options.add_argument("-headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, firefox_options=options)
```

Am I missing any parameter to inform Firefox to not preview the pdf file but rather download it? Firefox doesn't save the file and keeps opening the preview when I fire a click() in an object that points to a .pdf file.

The Firefox version is 60.0.

Example HTML:

```
<a id=pdfdownload href="/some/path/somefile.pdf">LINK</a>
```

python code:

```
obj = driver.find_element_by_id("pdfdownload")
obj.click()
```

This is only an example, to display the way I'm interacting with the objects in screeen.

Comment: Relevant HTML please

Comment: I'll provide one soon, but it's not working in ANY pdf download link.

Answer (score 0):

This line disables pdf opening when download is complete

```
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
```